# Android Webview, scale content to fit screen

Tags: java, android, webview

My friend made an application using javascript, and uploaded it to his website.

Now I'm trying to wrap it into a webview in android, and that's working fine in some ways.

The page is 480x320

But no matter what screensize I select on Android, there is a white space at the bottom on the  webview. I have tried a lot of ways to make it zoom, but nothing worked.

My code at this moment is this

```
    final WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);   
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.loadUrl("http://page.xx");
```

Comment: could you paste your xml file here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
wb.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.style.zoom = "+String.valueOf(scale)+";");
```

Where `scale` is a float, which you could calculate - I think in your case you want something like the following: `browser.getHeight() / 480dp`.
Load this Url after your webpage has finished loading.

Comment: wb would be your webView instance

Comment: +1. Thank you for sharing this. It led me in the right direction. I have also tried `document.body.style.zoom = window.innerHeight / 480;`. I loaded this script in `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()`.

Comment: I had a better experience using CSS transforms to scale my website rather than `zoom`. Text rendered better and so did `canvas` elements.

Comment: @Nick can you post an answer detailing your technique, others will probably benefit from it.

Answer (score 15):

I needed to scale-to-fit for the width and this variation of FunkTheMonk's answer worked well for me:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, String url)
{
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    manager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    metrics.widthPixels /= metrics.density;

    loadUrl("javascript:var scale = " + metrics.widthPixels + " / document.body.scrollWidth; document.body.style.zoom = scale;");
}
```

Comment: Works fine for the width, but how to scale content to fit width or height depending on ratio?

Answer (score 3):

Can you try to add :

```
browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
browser.setInitialScale(1);
browser.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

And see if it's working ?

Comment: Didnt to any diffrence at all.